# How to do first-of-type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaaf6us4/7/)

Here is my HTML

```
<div class='cl' data-gen='1'>One</div>
<div class='cl'  data-gen='5'>Two</div>
<div class='cl'  data-gen='6'>Three</div>
<br>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Alpha</div>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Andrew</div>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Christ</div>
<div class='jl jl_5' style='display:none'>Anto</div>
<div class='jl jl_5' style='display:none'>Brito</div>
<div class='jl jl_6' style='display:none'>Oyster</div>
<div class='jl jl_6' style='display:none'>Beta</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(document).on('click','.cl',function(){
   $('.jl').hide().filter('.jl_' + $(this).data('gen') ).show();
})
```

I want to display the first `jl_1` by default. How can i do this ?

Help pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger click on the first one.

```
$('.cl').first().click();
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aaaf6us4/8/)**

Answer (score 3):

#### Without JavaScript:

I would just leave the `display: none` off the first one in the markup.

#### With JavaScript:

But if you need to use JavaScript for it, then I would make your "show" function reusable:

```
function jlShow(entry) {
   $('.jl').hide().filter('.jl_' + entry ).show();
}
```

then:

```
jlShow(1);
$(document).on('click','.cl',function(){
   jlShow( $(this).data('gen') );
});
```

That way, if you need to change the selectors, etc., you're doing it in **one** place, not multiple places.

---

Side note: `data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It sets up the jQuery data cache for the element. If you just want the attribute, use `attr`, not `data`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to display the first jl_1 by default. How can i do this ?

Set first `.jl_1` element `style` to `display:block` at `html`

```
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:block'>Alpha</div>
```

Comment: ...or just...leave out `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".jl_1:first").show();`

```js
$(".jl_1:first").show();

$(document).on('click','.cl',function(){
   $('.jl').hide().filter('.jl_' + $(this).data('gen') ).show();
  //$(".jl_1:first").show();  //If you want to show it always
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cl' data-gen='1'>One</div>
<div class='cl'  data-gen='5'>Two</div>
<div class='cl'  data-gen='6'>Three</div>
<br>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Alpha</div>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Andrew</div>
<div class='jl jl_1' style='display:none'>Christ</div>
<div class='jl jl_5' style='display:none'>Anto</div>
<div class='jl jl_5' style='display:none'>Brito</div>
<div class='jl jl_6' style='display:none'>Oyster</div>
<div class='jl jl_6' style='display:none'>Beta</div>
```